# Splitting Table Of Contents into two halves

Tags: table-of-contents

I want my table of contents to be displayed in two halves side by side on the same page, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way with `multicol` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begingroup% In order to make local the \columnsep change bellow
% As @Mico suggested you may handle the separation space of the columns
% by un-commenting the next line:
%\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\endgroup
\part{part A}
\section{Test A}
Test
\section{Test B}

\subsection{Test BA}
\subsection{Test BB}
\section{Test C}
\section{Text D}
\part{part B}
\section{Test A}
Test
\section{Test B}

\subsection{Test BA}
\subsection{Test BB}
\section{Test C}
\section{Text D}
\part{part C}
\section{Test A}
Test
\section{Test B}

\subsection{Test BA}
\subsection{Test BB}
\section{Test C}
\section{Text D}
\part{part D}
\section{Test A}
Test
\section{Test B}

\subsection{Test BA}
\subsection{Test BB}
\section{Test C}
\section{Text D}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also see this post that allows many many things in customizing any "table of ...": https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503458/120578

Comment: +1. You may want to add a comment to point out that if the OP wants to increase the horizontal distance between the columns, he/she can do so by changing the value of the length parameter `\columsep`; e.g., `\setlength\columnsep{20pt}`. (The default value of the parameter in most document classes is `10pt`.)

Comment: Thanks @Mico ... Added your comment's suggestion in the code given.

Answer (score 1):

The `tocloft` and `multicol` package help with this.

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{multicol}
% twocolumn ToC
\renewcommand{\cfttocprehook{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand{\cfttocposthook}{\end{multicols}}
% twocolumn LoF (if required)
 \renewcommand{\cftlofprehook{\begin{multicols}{2}}
 \renewcommand{\cftlofposthook}{\end{multicols}}
% twocolumn LoT (if required)
 \renewcommand{\cftlotprehook{\begin{multicols}{2}}
 \renewcommand{\cftlotposthook}{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % in twocolumn
\listoffigures   % in twocolumn if \cftlofp... renewed 
\listoftables    % in twocolumn if \cftlotp... renewed
% etc
\end{document}
```